# excel macro calling another excel macro in vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have made a macro that calls another macro saved on my shared drive. I have taken the help from the suggestions given in the previous question I asked. It is working on the files that are on my local drive, but as soon as I open it from a file from the shared drive it stops working.

The macro name is `mymacro.xla`

These are the codes:

```
Dim i As AddIn

Set i = Application.AddIns.Add("M:\nit\USER\nitin kumar\NQK\macro\run1.2.xla", True)

i.Installed = True
```

I have created a button whose codes is given below:

```
Dim CoBa As CommandBar
Dim Ctlconst As CommandBarControl
On Error Resume Next

Set CoBa = Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:="Quote Daily Report", temporary:=True)

With CoBa
    Set Ctlconst = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)

    With Ctlconst
        .Caption = "Lexington Macro"
        .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaptionBelow
        .OnAction = "Accounts_Summary"
        .FaceId = 483
        .TooltipText = "NITIN"
    End With
    .Visible = True
    .Position = msoBarBottom
End With
```

It's not working any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Maybe the file is opened by another user? Excel locks the file(s) excelusively.
Also: Is the path a UNC-path like server://? If so, maybe Excel refuses to open CMD paths? The CMD does so, so that would be my guess.

Answer (score 0):

The least effort solution would be to copy the XLA locally before adding it.

The root cause could be one a number of things, locking, a read-only folder or security restrictions.  It's better not to mess about with that and also that gets you around a bunch of potential problems such as:- what happens if you update the xla while someone is using it?

Comment: sir while the .xal file is working on the local drive it is overriding the addins folder and adding it to the microsoft folder and when it is working on the shared drive it is not performing on the same.while working on the local drive it is working fine but not on the shared file.

Comment: I know it doesn't work on the shared drive, that was in your question - so what part of *copy the XLA locally* is it that you are having trouble with?

Comment: copying it on the local drive it has already been done the microsoft folder is actually on the local drive i have called them as an addins and under the app folder i have them added but the file is in the shared drive and it is not working on them i have to work on many a files and copy all of them on the .

Comment: Instead of copying to the addins folder (which is generally not recommended anyway) copy it to another folder such as in the user profile using one of the file copy commands and add that when you do your `AddIns.Add` call.